# Append a button at the end of options in react-select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I am using [react-select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select) library to implement search and select functionality in my project.

As a basic usage, I can only select the options returned after the search. It looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9RTF.png) whose code is:

```
<AsyncSelect
       onChange={(item) => _selectedItemChange(item)}
       loadOptions={loadItemOptions}
       placeholder='Start typing'
 />
```

Now, I want a button at the lower end of the select box so that I can do like 'Not found? Add New' type of stuff. Something like  [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRFd8.png). I also want that button's onClick function to be my own.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you show the code for this `AsyncSelect` component?

Comment: you just have to append your button to loadItemOptions but add more code here to clarify the problem

Comment: You can just use AsyncCreatable. It allows to create new items on demand (you just need to type what you want)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the answer of @PasVV, I was able to make something, I have wanted to.
By passing props to the AsyncSelect Component, we can make our own custom Menu(Customizable component in react-select) as follows.

```
const CustomMenu = ({ innerRef, innerProps, isDisabled, children }) =>
        !isDisabled ? (
            <div ref={innerRef} {...innerProps} className="customReactSelectMenu">
                {children}
                <button
                    className="btn btn-info btn-sm btn-block"
                    onClick={() => ...}
                >Add New</button>
            </div>
        ) : null;
```

And passing it to `<AsyncSelect/>`

```
<AsyncSelect
        onChange={_change}
        loadOptions={loadVendorOptions}
        placeholder='Start typing'
        components={{ Menu: CustomMenu }}
/>
```

Answer (score 9):

```
import { components } from 'react-select';

const SelectMenuButton = (props) => {
    return (
        <components.MenuList  {...props}>
            {props.children}
            <button>Add new element</button>
        </components.MenuList >
    ) }

<Select   components={{ MenuList: SelectMenuButton }} />
```

Comment: Can you add some explanations for your code?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your goal, you may [replace](https://react-select.com/props#replacing-components) logic of react-select `MenuList` component.

You can find some examples in [documentation](https://react-select.com/components#replaceable-components).

I suppose it is the best way to add some custom functionality in your react-select component.

Answer (score 0):

To view the edit delete button on each option use the below code.

```
import React from "react";
import { option_data } from "./data";
import { components } from "react-select";
import AsyncCreatableSelect from "react-select/async-creatable";

const Option = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <components.Option {...props}>
        <div
          style={{
            display: "flex",
            flexDirection: "row",
            justifyContent: "space-between"
          }}
        >
          <div>{props.children}</div>
          <div>
            <button
              onClick={(e) => {
                e.stopPropagation();
                console.log("Delete clicked: ", props.data.id);
              }}
            >
              Edit
            </button>
            <button
              onClick={(e) => {
                e.stopPropagation();
                console.log("Delete clicked: ", props.data.id);
              }}
            >
              Delete
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </components.Option>
    </>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const filterInput = (inputValue) => {
    return option_data.filter((i) =>
      i.label.toLowerCase().includes(inputValue.toLowerCase())
    );
  };

  const promiseOptions = (inputValue) =>
    new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(filterInput(inputValue));
      }, 1000);
    });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <AsyncCreatableSelect
        components={{ Option }}
        loadOptions={promiseOptions}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[codesandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-async-creatable-select-with-edit-delete-option-8p27kp?file=/src/App.js)